# Pgadmin4 won't show on windows 10 system tray

Tags: windows-10, pgadmin-4

I just installed PostgreSQL's latest version and opened pgadmin4, it actually shows the UI but somehow it **won't show on the system tray as the image below**. I wanted the pgadmin4 opened on my browser instead of the application, that's why I'm looking for it on the system tray, any answer would be appreciated, thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v5, pgAdmin desktop will open in an NWjs container. The system tray is discontinued in support of a desktop app feel.